# Wake up the app over the lock screen on Android 6.0+ devices

Tags: java, android, voip

I am now building a VoIp Android app and I'd like to show the incoming call screen over the lock screen even though the app is closed.
Exactly like `WhatsApp`.
I tried many solutions but they are all old and the APIs for  `PowerManager`and other APIs are deprecated in Android 6.0+.

Can anyone tell me the best solution?